# Can the ScrollPane act like a Divider?

Tags: java, jscrollpane, divide, jsplitpane

I am trying to add into my Frame a scrollpane. But my Question is can the scrollpane divide and How I can add it.

```
JPanel leftPanel = leftSection();
    JPanel centerPanel = middleSection();
    JPanel rightPanel = rigntSection();

    JSplitPane splitPane1 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftPanel, centerPanel);


    JSplitPane splitPane2 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, splitPane1, rightPanel); //--> I wanna add it here but dont know how.


    splitPane1.setVisible(true);
    splitPane2.setVisible(true);
```

This code works but I dont know how to implement a Scrollpane in Splitpane.

Best Regard

Manuellsen

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the pane(s) with JScrolPane
e.g.

```
JSplitPane splitPane1 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, 
    new JScrollPane(leftPanel), new JScrollPane(centerPanel));
```

Comment: It does not work because JScrollpane() want to have an int and give me a error because the constructor get JPane

Comment: It should work since JScrollPane has a constructor with only a Component as an argument. As for the 'int' thing - try using ScrollPaneConstants with the relevant constants (e.g. HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR, HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS)